# java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity, passing to another activity

Tags: java, android, compiler-errors

I've been trying to do everything but nothing worked, I want to pass from the `LogInActivity`to the `RegisterUserActivity` by clicking a button, but it doesn't work.

I get a java.lang.RuntimeException, help please, here is my code:

**LoginActivity:**

```
public class LoginActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener{
    private static final String LOGIN_URL = "http://ucwm.co.nf/UsuarioLogin_app.php";


    // Email, password edittext
    EditText txtUsername;
    EditText txtPassword;

    Button btnReg;

    // login button
    Button btnLogin;

    // Alert Dialog Manager
    AlertDialogManager alert = new AlertDialogManager();

    // Session Manager Class
    SessionManager session;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.login_layout);

        // Session Manager
        session = new SessionManager(getApplicationContext());

        // Email, Password input text
        txtUsername = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.userName);
        txtPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.passwordUser);

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "User Login Status: " + session.isLoggedIn(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        if(session.isLoggedIn()){
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
            finish();
        }

        // Login button
        btnLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.loginButton);

        btnLogin.setOnClickListener(this);

        btnReg=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnReg);

        btnReg.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

    private void login(){
        String username = txtUsername.getText().toString().trim();
        String password = txtPassword.getText().toString().trim();
        userLogin(username, password);
    }

    private void userLogin(final String username, final String password){
        class UserLoginClass extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String> {

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
                super.onPostExecute(s);
                if (username.trim().length() > 0 && password.trim().length() > 0){
                    if (s.equalsIgnoreCase("exito")) {

                        // Creating user login session
                        // For testing i am stroing name, email as follow
                        // Use user real data
                        session.createLoginSession(username);

                        // set
                        ((Usuario) getApplication()).setSomeVariable(username);

                        // Staring MainActivity
                        Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
                        startActivity(i);
                        finish();


                    } else {
                        //Error en username o password
                        alert.showAlertDialog(LoginActivity.this, "Fallo inicio de sesión..", "Usuario o Contraseña incorrecto", false);
                    }
            }
                else{
                    // user didn't entered username or password
                    // Show alert asking him to enter the details
                    alert.showAlertDialog(LoginActivity.this, "Fallo inicio de sesión..", "Porfavor ingrese usuario y contraseña", false);
                }
            }

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
                HashMap<String,String> data = new HashMap<>();
                data.put("username",params[0]);
                data.put("contrasenia",params[1]);

                RegisterUserClass ruc = new RegisterUserClass();

                String result = ruc.sendPostRequest(LOGIN_URL,data);

                return result;
            }
        }
        UserLoginClass ulc = new UserLoginClass();
        ulc.execute(username, password);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if(v == btnLogin){
            SharedPreferences preferences = this.getSharedPreferences("PREFERENCE", 0);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
            editor.putBoolean("PREFERENCE",true);
            login();
        }
        if(v==btnReg){
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), RegisterUserAcivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
            finish();
        }
    }
}
```

**RegisterUserActivity:**

```
public class RegisterUserAcivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{

private RadioGroup radioPrefijo;
private RadioButton radioPre;
private EditText editTextName;
private EditText editTextUsername;
private EditText editTextPassword;
private EditText editTextEmail;
private EditText editTextDate;
private EditText editTextLastName;
private EditText editTextTelefone;

Calendar myCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();

String prefijo;

private Button buttonRegister;

private static final String REGISTER_URL = "http://ucwm.co.nf/UsuarioRegister_app.php";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.register_layout);

    editTextName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextNombre);
    editTextUsername = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextUsername);
    editTextPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextContrasenia);
    editTextTelefone = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextTelefono);
    editTextEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextEmail);
    editTextDate = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextFechaNac);
    editTextLastName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextApellido);

    buttonRegister = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnRegistro);

    addListenerOnButton();

    buttonRegister.setOnClickListener(this);

    editTextDate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            new DatePickerDialog(RegisterUserAcivity.this, date, myCalendar
                    .get(Calendar.YEAR), myCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                    myCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)).show();
        }
    });

}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if(v == buttonRegister){
        registerUser();
        finish();
    }
}

private void registerUser() {
    String name = editTextName.getText().toString();
    String lastName = editTextLastName.getText().toString().trim();
    String username = editTextUsername.getText().toString().trim();
    String password = editTextPassword.getText().toString().trim();
    String telefono = editTextTelefone.getText().toString().trim();
    String email = editTextEmail.getText().toString().trim().toLowerCase();
    String date = editTextDate.getText().toString().trim().toLowerCase();
    String pref= prefijo;

    register(username,password,name,lastName,date,email,telefono,pref);
}

private void register(String username,String password,String name,String lastName,String date,String email,String telefono,String pref) {
    class RegisterUser extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{
        ProgressDialog loading;
        RegisterUserClass ruc = new RegisterUserClass();

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            super.onPostExecute(s);
            loading.dismiss();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),s,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

            HashMap<String, String> data = new HashMap<String,String>();
            data.put("username",params[0]);
            data.put("password",params[1]);
            data.put("name",params[2]);
            data.put("lastname",params[3]);
            data.put("date",params[4]);
            data.put("email",params[5]);
            data.put("telefono",params[6]);
            data.put("prefijo",params[7]);

            String result = ruc.sendPostRequest(REGISTER_URL,data);

            return  result;
        }
    }

    RegisterUser ru = new RegisterUser();
    ru.execute(username,password,name,lastName,date,email,telefono,pref);
}

public void addListenerOnButton() {

    radioPrefijo = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioPref);

    int p = radioPrefijo.getCheckedRadioButtonId();

    radioPre = (RadioButton) findViewById(p);
    prefijo = radioPre.getText().toString();

}

DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener date = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

    @Override
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear,
                          int dayOfMonth) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        myCalendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
        myCalendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthOfYear);
        myCalendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth);
        updateLabel();
    }

};


private void updateLabel() {
    String myFormat = "yy-MM-dd"; //In which you need put here
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(myFormat, Locale.US);
    editTextDate.setText(sdf.format(myCalendar.getTime()));
}

}
```

**LoginActivity xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">

<EditText
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/userName"
    android:hint="Usuario"
    android:layout_above="@+id/textView14"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView14"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView14"
    android:layout_marginBottom="41dp" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/passwordUser"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:hint="Contraseña"
    android:editable="false"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:inputType="textPassword" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Iniciar Sesión"
    android:id="@+id/loginButton"
    android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/passwordUser"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Ingrese Usuario"
    android:id="@+id/textView12"
    android:layout_above="@+id/userName"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/userName"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/userName" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Ingrese Contresña"
    android:id="@+id/textView14"
    android:layout_above="@+id/passwordUser"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/passwordUser"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/passwordUser" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Registrarse"
    android:id="@+id/btnReg"
    android:layout_below="@+id/loginButton"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/loginButton"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/loginButton" />
```

**RegisterActivity xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Nombre (s)"
        android:id="@+id/textView15"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView18"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView18" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/editTextNombre"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Apellido (s)"
        android:id="@+id/textView16"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editTextNombre"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/editTextApellido"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView16"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Nombre de Usuario"
        android:id="@+id/textView17"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editTextApellido"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/editTextUsername"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView17"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Contraseña"
        android:id="@+id/textView21" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/editTextContrasenia" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Teléfono"
        android:id="@+id/textView18"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editTextTelefono"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView20"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/textView20" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/editTextTelefono"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView20"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Fecha de Nacimiento"
        android:id="@+id/textView19"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editTextFechaNac"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="date"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/editTextFechaNac" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Correo"
        android:id="@+id/textView20"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editTextUsername"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/editTextEmail" />

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/radioPref"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Usuario"
            android:id="@+id/radioButtonUser"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/radioButtonMedic"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/editTextNombre"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/editTextNombre"
            android:checked="false" />

        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:text="Médico"
            android:id="@+id/radioButtonMedic"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/editTextNombre"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/editTextNombre"
            android:checked="false" />

    </RadioGroup>



    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Registrarse"
        android:id="@+id/btnRegistro"
        android:layout_below="@+id/radioButtonUser"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="35dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**manifest**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.juanisaac.unidascontigoac">

<!--PERMISOS-->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

<!--ICONO DE LA APP-->
<application
    android:name="Usuario"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    android:largeHeap="true">

        <activity
            android:name=".LoginActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <!-- DashBoard / MainActivity -->
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".SettingsActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_settings">
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".TestimoniosDetallados"
        android:label="Testimonios Detallados">
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".AniadirForo"
        android:label="Añadir Foro">
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".ForoDetallado"
        android:label="Foro Detallado">
    </activity>
    <activity
    android:name=".EventoDetallado"
    android:label="Evento Detallado">
</activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".RegisterUserAcivity"
        android:label="Register Activity">
    </activity>
    <!--
    <activity
        android:name=".SettingsActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_settings" >
    </activity>
    -->
</application>
```

Here is the LOGCAT that it displays:

```
11-27 00:36:01.540  24273-24273/com.example.juanisaac.unidascontigoac D/dalvikvm﹕ Late-enabling CheckJNI
11-27 00:36:02.540  24273-24273/com.example.juanisaac.unidascontigoac D/libEGL﹕ loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_genymotion.so
11-27 00:36:02.576  24273-24273/com.example.juanisaac.unidascontigoac D/﹕ HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xb80bc298, tid 24273
11-27 00:36:02.604  24273-24273/com.example.juanisaac.unidascontigoac D/libEGL﹕ loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_genymotion.so
11-27 00:36:02.608  24273-24273/com.example.juanisaac.unidascontigoac D/libEGL﹕ loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_genymotion.so
11-27 00:36:03.036  24273-24273/com.example.juanisaac.unidascontigoac W/EGL_genymotion﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
11-27 00:36:03.060  24273-24273/com.example.juanisaac.unidascontigoac D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Enabling debug mode 0
11-27 00:37:54.167  24273-24273/com.example.juanisaac.unidascontigoac I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 36 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-27 00:37:54.307  24273-24273/com.example.juanisaac.unidascontigoac W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Landroid/view/SearchEvent;)
11-27 00:37:54.323  24273-24273/com.example.juanisaac.unidascontigoac I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.view.Window$Callback.onSearchRequested, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onSearchRequested
11-27 00:37:54.323  24273-24273/com.example.juanisaac.unidascontigoac W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve interface method 15466: Landroid/view/Window$Callback;.onSearchRequested (Landroid/view/SearchEvent;)Z
11-27 00:37:54.327  24273-24273/com.example.juanisaac.unidascontigoac D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x72 at 0x0002
11-27 00:37:54.335  24273-24273/com.example.juanisaac.unidascontigoac I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.view.Window$Callback.onWindowStartingActionMode, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onWindowStartingActionMode
11-27 00:37:54.339  24273-24273/com.example.juanisaac.unidascontigoac W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve interface method 15470: Landroid/view/Window$Callback;.onWindowStartingActionMode (Landroid/view/ActionMode$Callback;I)Landroid/view/ActionMode;
11-27 00:37:54.339  24273-24273/com.example.juanisaac.unidascontigoac D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x72 at 0x0002
11-27 00:37:54.407  24273-24273/com.example.juanisaac.unidascontigoac I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.ResourcesWrapper.getDrawable
11-27 00:37:54.407  24273-24273/com.example.juanisaac.unidascontigoac W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 405: Landroid/content/res/Resources;.getDrawable (ILandroid/content/res/Resources$Theme;)Landroid/graphics/drawable/Drawable;
11-27 00:37:54.411  24273-24273/com.example.juanisaac.unidascontigoac D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
11-27 00:37:54.415  24273-24273/com.example.juanisaac.unidascontigoac I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.content.res.Resources.getDrawableForDensity, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.ResourcesWrapper.getDrawableForDensity
11-27 00:37:54.419  24273-24273/com.example.juanisaac.unidascontigoac W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 407: Landroid/content/res/Resources;.getDrawableForDensity (IILandroid/content/res/Resources$Theme;)Landroid/graphics/drawable/Drawable;
11-27 00:37:54.423  24273-24273/com.example.juanisaac.unidascontigoac D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
11-27 00:37:54.463  24273-24276/com.example.juanisaac.unidascontigoac D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_CONCURRENT freed 221K, 3% free 8787K/9036K, paused 6ms+6ms, total 25ms
11-27 00:37:54.479  24273-24273/com.example.juanisaac.unidascontigoac D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
11-27 00:37:54.483  24273-24273/com.example.juanisaac.unidascontigoac W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xa6195908)
11-27 00:37:54.487  24273-24273/com.example.juanisaac.unidascontigoac E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.juanisaac.unidascontigoac/com.example.juanisaac.unidascontigoac.RegisterUserAcivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.example.juanisaac.unidascontigoac.RegisterUserAcivity.addListenerOnButton(RegisterUserAcivity.java:143)
            at com.example.juanisaac.unidascontigoac.RegisterUserAcivity.onCreate(RegisterUserAcivity.java:58)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-27 00:37:57.967  24273-24273/com.example.juanisaac.unidascontigoac I/Process﹕ Sending signal. PID: 24273 SIG: 9
```

Comment: what is RegisterUserAcivity.java:  line 58, you are getting a null pointer there

Comment: what is on line 58 in RegisterUserAcivity

Comment: IMO, you should check `int p = radioPrefijo.getCheckedRadioButtonId();`, make sure it returns the resourceId of the radiobutton, not the index of it

Comment: your main error is on this line RegisterUserAcivity.java:143

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here:

```
prefijo = radioPre.getText().toString();
```

line causing issue because `radioPre` is `null`.

[getCheckedRadioButtonId()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RadioGroup.html#getCheckedRadioButtonId()) method return  `-1` *if not checked RadioButton found in RadioGroup*.

So in current RadioGroup xml all RadioButton `android:checked` property is set to `android:checked="false"`  so no checked RadioButton available in RadioGroup and `getCheckedRadioButtonId()` will return `-1`.

To fix current issue add if condition  before accessing RadioButton :

```
if(p !=-1){
    radioPre = (RadioButton) findViewById(p);
    prefijo = radioPre.getText().toString();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**You've got problem here:**

```
public void addListenerOnButton() {

radioPrefijo = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioPref);

int p = radioPrefijo.getCheckedRadioButtonId();

radioPre = (RadioButton) findViewById(p);

prefijo = radioPre.getText().toString();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You must perform error checking here

```
public void addListenerOnButton() {

    radioPrefijo = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioPref);

    int p = radioPrefijo.getCheckedRadioButtonId();

    radioPre = (RadioButton) findViewById(p);
    prefijo = radioPre.getText().toString();

}
```

because radioPrefijo.getCheckedRadioButtonId() can return -1 if case of non button checked. So in this case findViewById returns null and you are getting the exception

So you need to set one of your radio buttons checked by default or add this if to your code

```
int p = radioPrefijo.getCheckedRadioButtonId();

if (p > 0){ 
    radioPre = (RadioButton) findViewById(p);
    prefijo = radioPre.getText().toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are calling finish() while your registration task is active in background on line #58

```
  registerUser();
        finish();
```

& in Yor async task you are using reference of class variable myCalendar which got cleaned because activity is finished on line #143

```
private void updateLabel() {
    String myFormat = "yy-MM-dd"; //In which you need put here
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(myFormat, Locale.US);
    editTextDate.setText(sdf.format(myCalendar.getTime()));
}
```

Your Calendar instance is causing null pointer exception.

```
public class RegisterUserAcivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{
...
...

Calendar myCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
```

I suggest you finish your activity in postExecute  of Async task.